# class.upload.php failing in CentOS 7.6 LEMP droplet

Tags: php, linux, nginx, file-upload, centos7.6

Long story short:

I was hosting my MVC PHP application in Amazon Web Services in a LEMP Instance.

I then decided to move to Digital Ocean because their instances are not allowed to send emails.

My app, in the AWS instance, was able to upload photos, write to the database, and communicate with an external API.

In Digital Ocean, however, I’m not able to upload photos with [class.upload.php](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm). In /var/log/nginx/error.log this is the output:

```
2020/05/18 03:28:17 [error] 10851#0: *174 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /usr/share/nginx/html/admin/core/controller/class.upload.php on line 2667 PHP message: PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /usr/share/nginx/html/admin/core/controller/class.upload.php on line 2667" while reading response header from upstream, client: 181.115.109.228, server: _, request: "POST /admin/index.php?action=addproduct HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "165.227.91.80", referrer: "http://165.227.91.80/admin/index.php?view=newproduct"
```

You’d believe that there’s an error in class.upload.php on line 2667, however, this is not the case. As I’m telling you, everything works as intended in AWS. `/var/log/php-fpm/error.log` does not show any error. This is the output:

```
[18-May-2020 01:39:40] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 10826
[18-May-2020 01:39:40] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[18-May-2020 01:39:40] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

The upload directory is `/usr/share/nginx/html/admin/storage` I've set the permissions are set to `777`.
What could I be doing wrong?.
My PHP version is `PHP 7.3.18 (cli).`
This is the PHP code that adds a product to the database.

```
$product = new ProductData();
    foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
       if($k=="existence"){
           if($v==""){
            $product->existence=12;
           }else{
            $product->$k = $v;
           }
       }else{
        $product->$k = $v;

       }
    }

    $alphabeth = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ1234567890_-";
    $code = "";
    for ($i = 0;$i < 11;$i++) {
        $code.= $alphabeth[rand(0, strlen($alphabeth) - 1) ];
    }
    $product->short_name = $code;
    $handle = new Upload($_FILES['image']);
    if ($handle->uploaded) {
        $url = "storage/products/";
        $handle->Process($url);
        $product->image = $handle->file_dst_name;
    }
    if (isset($_POST["is_public"])) {
        $product->is_public = 1;
    } else {
        $product->is_public = 0;
    }
    if (isset($_POST["in_existence"])) {
        $product->in_existence = 1;
    } else {
        $product->in_existence = 0;
    }
    if (isset($_POST["is_featured"])) {
        $product->is_featured = 1;
    } else {
        $product->is_featured = 0;
    }
    if (isset($_POST["doublePoints"])) {
        $product->doublePoints = 1;
    } else {
        $product->doublePoints = 0;
    }
    // $product->name = $_POST["name"];
    $product->add();
    Core::redir("index.php?view=products");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELinux was `disabled` in the AWS instance and `enforcing` in DigitalOcean.
I just had to disable it in order to upload files.